# Plotting a density function implied by stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, density-function

This might be a very simple question, but I don't know what the best way is to plot a probability density function implied by a system of stochastic differential equations. Particularly, the equations would be the following:
$$
dF_t = \alpha_t\,F_t^{\beta}\,dB_t \\
d\alpha_t = \nu\,\alpha_t\,dW_t \\
dB_tdW_t = \rho\,dt
$$

Where $W$ and $B$ are different Brownian motions.

The question is, how can I plot **the pdf of the process $F$** for some given $\beta$, $\nu$ and $\rho$ constants?